# Hardware Accelerated BufferedImage on a laptop with two GPUs

Tags: java, eclipse, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I have done much research into Java accelerated graphics and have determined that none of my BufferedImages or VolatileImages are being accelerated - in fact, hardware acceleration is not even supported on my laptop, as

```
GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleVolatileImage(width, height, new ImageCapabilities(true));
```

throws an exception that tells me so. However, my laptop has an NVIDIA 650m which should be more than capable of doing this. The problem (or so I think) is that the alternative HP integrated graphics chip (used by default for most non-gpu-intensive applications) is being used by Java instead. How can I tell Java to use the NVIDIA card? I have tried forcing java.exe and javaw.exe to use it via the NVIDIA control panel but to no avail.

I realize that this is less of a java question and more a problem related to my specific hardware, but I do not exactly understand the process by which java and Eclipse IDE go about utilizing my hardware. Is it possible that I need to change some settings or command line parameters in Eclipse as well? Even if you can't provide a precise answer, just some pointers in the right direction or to what I should research next would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you used this flag `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true`

And which Java-Version do you use?